# Заполнение ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно заполнить ListView(WinForms) на форме из List?
В List содержится три поля, имя, фамилия и id студента.

```
 public static List<string> Students()
    {
        List<string> listStudents = new List<string>();

            listStudents.Add($"{firstName} {lastName} {id}");
         return listStudents;
    }
```

Как правильно их подвязать к ListView формы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте для начала создадим модель предметной области:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Сделаем типизированный список:

```
List<Student> listStudents = new List<Student>();
```

Соответственно, в этот список будем добавлять экземпляры этого класса, а не строки:

```
var student = new Student { Id = id, FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastName };
listStudents.Add(student);
```

Далее. Предлагаю вместо `ListView` использовать `DataGridView`. Он позволяет использовать привязку данных (data binding) всего одной строкой:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = listStudents;
```

Всё! В гриде будет симпатичный список с колонками всех студентов.

Comment: ну или если надо именно listbox то лучше wpf и изменить ItemTemplate